# Div overflowing on higher resolutions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying for awhile now to center a div and kept it from overflowing on higher resolutions(1920 x 1200 and up), I tried adding `width:auto` or using positioning but nothing is working so I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

This is my div:

[image]

And this is what happens on higher resolutions:

[image]

This div is within another one so here it is both the css and html for both:

```
/*Parent*/
.main-graphic-container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-right: 75px;
    padding-left: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}

/*Child*/
.feature-container {
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top:80px;
    margin-left:45px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #888888;
    background-color: #ffffff;

}

<div class="container main-graphic-container"> 
    <div class="row">

    ...

    </div>
    <!-- end row -->

<!-- Child container so troublesome-->
<div class="container "> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="center-block">
            <h1 class="greyText col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET.  </h1>
            <!-- Title -->

            <!-- Info container -->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 feature-container">

            <!-- Left -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4 class="bold blue-title text-center">Lorem ipsum</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Right -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4 class="grey-title">Lorem ipsum</h4>
            </div>

        </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use  media query to change your css after resolutions(1920 x 1200 and up)

Comment: have you tried to use **media queries** yet? They are perfect for resizing different elements of the document, when the screen resolution changes. Here are some links you should check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries, http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp and here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_breakpoints. Hope this Helps :)

Comment: @andihamolli thanks I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need little improvement in your code.
Try the below code for your issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  /*Parent*/
.head{
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-contain{
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: -45;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container"> 

<div class="head">
<h1>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET.  </h1>
</div> <!--head-->

<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 sub-contain">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h4 class="bold blue-title text-center">Lorem ipsum</h4>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<h4 class="grey-title">Lorem ipsum</h4>
</div>
</div>

</div><!--cont-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll check this out. A lot of improvements? Do you have any recommendations to avoid this kind of issues.Thanks

Comment: Just compare both code(Mine and Yours). If output come with small and simple css than no need to write big an complicated css.

Answer (score 2):

A working fiddle would be helpful in this case to see exactly what is going on.

However, some things that jump out at me:

- Assuming this is bootstrap CSS, you should never need nested `.container` elements.  If I'm not mistaken, `.container` gives you a fixed width which takes up most of the screen, so you shouldn't have two of them like this.
- Why is `.feature-container` absolute position?  It doesn't use `top`, `bottom`, `left`, or `right`... How is it trying to be positioned?  Is it just trying to be displayed outside its parent?  Just use negative margins, and `overflow: visible` if it is getting clipped.

Comment: Yes I used position absolute because I wanted the div to clip outside as show in the picture. I will try your tips shortly, thanks.